# Sketching within a Solution Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, errors, exam

I wish to sketch a set within a solution environment, but my attempts have led to the following error message:

```
LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

How do I fix this? Here is a snippet of my code

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam} % A4 paper and 11pt font size 

 \usepackage[english]{babel} % English language 
  \usepackage{tikz} % Tikz package for sketching 
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} %% American Mathematical Society packages

  \newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
 \question Let $\mathbf 0 = (0,0)$. Sketch the set $\{\x \in \mathbb R^2 d_m(\mathbf 0, x )\le 1\} $.
\begin{solution}
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale =3]
  \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw[thick, ->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5)
  \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption*{$d_m(\mathbb 0, \x) \le 1$
\end{figure}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
```

Comment: Well, what should we do with this? A single error message, and no code to work with!

Comment: Don't use a `figure` environment. That is, remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My apologies.

Comment: @egreg I need a caption.

Comment: @Matthew why do you need a caption, especiall as it's unnumbered just add the text under the tikz, you don't need `figure` or `\caption`

Comment: @Matthew Instead of `\draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);` you probably want something like `\draw[fill=gray] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);`, don't you?

Comment: @Jon Not necessarily.  There are many ways of indicating closed balls. For example pg 25 of Introduction to Topology by Mendelson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a `figure` environment, but a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam} % A4 paper and 11pt font size 

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language 
\usepackage{tikz} % Tikz package for sketching 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} %% American Mathematical Society packages

\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question 
  Let $\mathbf{0} = (0,0)$. Sketch the set 
  $\{\x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d_m(\mathbf{0}, \x)\le 1\}$.

\begin{solution}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale =3]
  \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw[thick, ->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Train yourself into typing `\mathbf{0}` and similar, you'll be happier.

Comment: If you really need a caption (but I can't see why), look at the `capt-of` or `caption` package.